# Question on ODE notation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I recently had a quiz on separable and exact differential equations.
The question was this:

**Answer using the exact method.

No points will be awarded for any other method.**
$$ y'(x) + y(x) = y(x)^2 $$

My question is that I'm confused with this type of notation. 
Whereas the usual exact differential equation would look like $Mdx + Ndy = 0$. 
This looks nothing like it.

So what I did was as follows: 
$$y'(x) + y(x) = y(x)^2$$
$$y' + x = x^2$$
$$y' + (x - x^2) = 0$$
$$(x - x^2)dx + dy = 0$$
Then I proceeded to solving it with the exact method and found my answer: 
$$y = \frac{x^3}{3} - \frac{x^2}{2} + c$$

Did I do this right? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$y'(x) + y(x) = y(x)^2$$
Rewrite the DE as:
$$\dfrac {dy}{dx}  + y(x) = y(x)^2$$
$$dy+ydx=y^2dx$$
$$dy+ydx-y^2dx=0$$
$$dy+y(1-y)dx=0$$

---

$$y'(x) + y(x) = y(x)^2$$
This line is not correct:
$$y' + x = x^2$$

The $y(x)$ does not mean $y \times x$ it means that $y$ is a function of the variable $x$.
$$y'(x) + y(x) = y(x)^2$$
Is just:
$$y' + y = y^2$$

Answer (score 0):

You have
$$y'+y=y^2 \implies \frac {y'}{y^2}+\frac {1}y=1$$ So, let $y=\frac 1z$ to make
$$z'-z+1=0$$ Now $z-1=u$ to make
$$u'-u=0$$
Now, it looks to be very simple. Solve for $u$ and go back to $z$ and $y$.